# greenplum STRING_AGG functions convert to hiveSQL

Tags: sql, hive, concatenation, hiveql, greenplum

We have to migrate greenplum sql to hivesql and below query is not supporing string_agg keyword. kindly help us.

```
select data_date, subscriber_id, msisdn, product, validity,
    STRING_AGG(d0,'xx') d0, STRING_AGG(d1,'') d1, STRING_AGG(d2,'') d2, STRING_AGG(d3,'') d3, STRING_AGG(d4,'') d4,
    STRING_AGG(d5,'') d5, STRING_AGG(d6,'') d6, STRING_AGG(d7,'') d7, STRING_AGG(d8,'') d8, STRING_AGG(d9,'') d9, STRING_AGG(d10,'') d10,
    STRING_AGG(d11,'') d11
from tmp_subscription_base_02
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

The string_agg is not supporting in hivesQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string_agg(expression, delimiter)` aggregation function can be replaced in Hive with

```
concat_ws(delimiter,collect_list(cast(expression as string))
```

Or if you need to concatenate DISTINCT values:

```
concat_ws(delimiter,collect_set(cast(expression as string))
```

Note: if `expression` is of type string, `cast(expression as string)` is not necessary, use `expression` as is.

Comment: please validate below query is correct

Comment: select data_date, subscriber_id, msisdn, product, validity,
concat_ws('xx',collect_list(cast(d0 as string))) d0, concat_ws('',collect_list(cast(d1 as string))) d1,
concat_ws('',collect_list(cast(d2 as string))) d2, concat_ws('',collect_list(cast(d3 as string)))

Comment: @karthikelavan yes, it should work.

Comment: thanks lot for your help, yes it is working fine